# How to import adobe Xd file to Axure?

Tags: adobe-xd, axure

I have an adobe xd file that I would like to import into axure if there's any way to do please help me

Thank you guys!

Comment: Have you checked your software documentation to see what file formats Axure supports?  Then check which formats XD can export to.

Answer (score 0):

This [blog post](https://www.axure.com/blog/import-adobe-xd-designs-into-axure) explains what you need

1. Install the [azure plug for XD](https://www.axure.cloud/download/?__hstc=257326932.cf4032bf481eae6b8a05f1be689a4da7.1629983248576.1629983248576.1629983248576.1&__hssc=257326932.1.1629983248576&__hsfp=3983281690).
2. Select the elements or art boards you’d like in Axure
3. Choose Plugins → Axure → Export selection to Axure Cloud.
4. Follow the prompts from there